# UITableView sort section

Tags: ipad, sorting

Is it possible to sort a UITableView section alphabetically?

I have an array of objects and in section 0 I have only one item from the array in this section. It could be any item in the array that I swap. section 1 will have the remainder of the objects in the array on display.

e.g.

A B C D

C A B D -- I want C to now be at section 0, the rest in alphabetical order in section 1

D A B C -- I want D to now be at section 0, the rest in alphabetical order in section 1

I've tried moving objects around, sorting and then moving but with no luck. Any suggestions would be great before I need to change it to a UIViewController with a Label and a UITableView below this label to simulate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the Object Array Alphabetically using sortUsingSelector (The array does need to be of type NSMutableArray rather than just a NSArray) and adding a method which returns an NSComparisonSort value in your Model Class. MyObject being the class of your Custom Object in this case. The sort is being done based on a letter property which is a NSString but could be something else.

```
// Just before wherever your Data Source is returned in your MyObject Class
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareTo:)];

// Method which does the Comparison, also in your MyObject
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTo:(MyObject *)otherObject {
    return [self.letter caseInsensitiveCompare:otherObject.letter];
}
```

Now to put the one object at Index 0, you could do the following. I assume you know the index of the object you want to take out...

```
MyObject *temp = [[myArray objectAtIndex:index] retain];
[myArray removeObject:temp];
[myArray insertObject:temp atIndex:0];
```

This preparation would be done before the Table View Delegate Methods are called. Possibly in your Table View Init or ViewWillLoad/ViewDidLoad

**Update**: Here is how to achieve the same Alphabetical sort using a SortDescriptor:

```
// This is setting up the Sort Descriptor for comparing the two objects based on the property 'letter'
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"letter" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter];

// This is the sorted array returned based on the property 'letter'
NSArray *sorted = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: ive tried this but I cannot get your NSComparisonResult correct. I need to compare two objects as opposed to self. Ive tried using a NSSortDescriptor as a replacement but no luck as well.

Comment: I've updated my post above to demonstrate using a sort descriptor. Hopefully it helps. Maybe posting some code would make it clearer

Comment: thanks my sort descriptor was working but what i failed to see was the folder 1 - test, 12 - test2, 13 - test 3, 4 - test 4 is sorting alphabetically which is correct. the removeObject and insertObject was the key, i didnt know what the behavior of insert would do, whether it pushes the array down which it appears to do. thanks